# Why does interpolation give me an error when I change the number of inputs

Tags: python, interpolation

Hello I was wondering why I get a LinAlgError: Singular Matrix when I change the amount of initial radii in a particular function.

Here's a rough outline of the working code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

tnew = np.linspace(.28, 13900, 1000)
x = np.linspace(.016, 4.52, 1000)
ri = np.arange(1.08E-3, 3.4E-3, 2.5E-4)

rho_b = 1/(6*pi*G*tnew**2) #background density
ti = .28 #initial time in Myr
ri1 = 8.3E-4 #initial radius of first shell
G = 4.52E-21 #Msun Mpc^-3 Myr^-2
di1 = -4.63E-3 #initial density contrast of first shell
t1 = (3*ti)/(4*abs(di1)**(1.5))*(sinh(x)-x) #time equation
rho_i1 = (di1+1)*rho_b[0] #initial density of first shell
M1 = (4./3)*pi*rho_i1*ri1**3 #initial mass of first shell
f = interp1d(t1,x, bounds_error=False, kind='cubic')
new_theta = f(tnew) 
Rv1 = (ri1/(2.*abs(di1)))*(cosh(new_theta)-1.) #final, evolved radius of first shell

for j in range(0, len(ri)):
    #set up initial density equations
    Mj = (4./3)*pi*rho_b[0]*(ri[j]**3 - ri1**3)
    vtot = (4./3)*pi*ri[j]**3
    rho_ij = (M1+Mj)/vtot

    #density contrast and time
    dij = (rho_ij/rho_b[0])-1
    tj= (3*ti)/(4*abs(dij)**(1.5))*(sinh(x)-x)

    #interpolation
    fj = interp1d(tj,x, bounds_error=False, kind='cubic')
    new_thetaj = fj(tnew)

    Rvj = (ri[j]/(2.*abs(dij)))*(cosh(new_thetaj)-1.)
```

I get the the final radii (Rvj) as expected and all is well, but as soon as i change my initial radius list (ri) to:

```
ri = np.linspace(1.08E-3, 3.4E-3, 50)
```

I get a Singular Matrix error.  I understand what it means, but I'm not sure why it comes up and how to fix it!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your whole code (especially imports)? I tried importing scipy and numpy, but symbols like `rho_b` can't get resolved...

Comment: Just edited the imports and initial conditions... should've realized those are quite important haha.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: In R I often get this error if the values in the matrix are too small which might be the case here, don't you think?

Comment: I was thinking that it might have to do with the size of the values, or perhaps the spacing between them.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still stuck on this error but I noticed that if you swap round the tj,x arguments supplied to interp1d, it no longer throws the singular matrix error. The function interp1d expects x and y arguments passed in that order so I would assume the arguments should be passed as shown seeing as you have defined tj in terms of x:

```
    fj = interp1d(x,tj, bounds_error=False, kind='cubic')
```

However this does throw an overflow warning for the following line but it at least allows the script to run through to the end.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I'd have to put in new x values into fj rather than tnew values?  I basically have a time that I need x (theta_new, sorry I've changed notation a bit throughout the code) values for.  I think swapping x and tj would mean I need to input new x rather than new t values right?  Thanks for looking into this!